# Getting value from push button that I can use in a new class/window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want the first window that opens up to contain 4 push buttons responding to the numbers: 2,3,4,5. Once I have pressed one of these buttons I want the window to close and a new window to open with a label (just so I know it works) and also to use that number as a separate variable as it will select a sheet that I am reading from an excel file.

At the moment I can create the first window with the boxes, and when I press one the new window opens - but I cannot get the selection I made to come across.

Here is as far as I have got so far...

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow

# select floor window
class select_floor_window(QDialog):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Select floor'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 100

        self.selection_ui()


    def selection_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.createHorizontalLayout()

        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)

        self.show()

    def createHorizontalLayout(self):

        # box layout
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Which floor are you on?")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # floor buttons
        floor_2_button = QPushButton("2", self)
        floor_2_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click2)
        layout.addWidget(floor_2_button)

        floor_3_button = QPushButton("3", self)
        floor_3_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click3)
        layout.addWidget(floor_3_button)

        floor_4_button = QPushButton("4", self)
        floor_4_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click4)
        layout.addWidget(floor_4_button)

        floor_5_button = QPushButton("5", self)
        floor_5_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click5)
        layout.addWidget(floor_5_button)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    # close this window and load main window
    def on_click2(self):
        self.floorchoice = 2
        self.show_main = main_Window()
        self.show_main.show()
        self.hide()
        print("2")
        return floorchoice

    def on_click3(self):
        self.floorchoice = 3
        self.show_main = main_Window()
        self.show_main.show()
        self.hide()
        print("3")
        return floorchoice

    def on_click4(self):
        self.floorchoice = 4
        self.show_main = main_Window()
        self.show_main.show()
        self.hide()
        print("4")
        return floorchoice

    def on_click5(self):
        self.floorchoice = 5
        self.show_main = main_Window()
        self.show_main.show()
        self.hide()
        print("5")
        return floorchoice



# create main window

class main_Window(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.title = "2ndwindow"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500        

        show_floor_button = QLabel(floorchoice, self)
        show_floor_button.move(100,100)


        # Close app button
        close_app_button = QPushButton("Exit", self)
        close_app_button.move(400,400)
        close_app_button.setToolTip("Close application")
        close_app_button.clicked.connect(self.CloseApp)

        self.InitWindow()


    # showing window
    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = select_floor_window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Anyway that I try to set up the code, it always says that "name 'floorchoice' is not defined" in the second window, and cannot get it to display the result from the first class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions that are invoked do not return anything, plus self.floorchoice is different floorchoice, the first is an attribute of the class and the other is a local variable.

What you have to do is that the class through the constructor or another method get that information.

In the next one I add one more argument to the invocation using functool.partial, then I pass that argument to the constructor of the other window so that I get that information.

I think your main error is caused by not taking into account that each variable, instance, object, etc. has a scope within the application.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow
from functools import partial

# select floor window
class select_floor_window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Select floor"
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 100

        self.selection_ui()

    def selection_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.createHorizontalLayout()
        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)

    def createHorizontalLayout(self):
        # box layout
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Which floor are you on?")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)
        # floor buttons
        for option in (2, 3, 4, 5):
            button = QPushButton(str(option))
            layout.addWidget(button)
            wrapper = partial(self.on_click, option)
            button.clicked.connect(wrapper)

    # close this window and load main window
    def on_click(self, option):
        self.show_main = main_Window(option)
        self.show_main.show()
        self.hide()


# create main window


class main_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, option, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.title = "2ndwindow"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500

        show_floor_button = QLabel(str(option), self)
        show_floor_button.move(100, 100)

        # Close app button
        close_app_button = QPushButton("Exit", self)
        close_app_button.move(400, 400)
        close_app_button.setToolTip("Close application")
        close_app_button.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.InitWindow()

    # showing window
    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = select_floor_window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly, and thanks for the advice, I will look more into where each variable can be accessed from and the partial function.